# How to view all packages in some overlay?

Tags: gentoo

I have some overlay installed. How I can see all packages in there ?

Comment: Isn't the whole tree downloaded to your disk just like the official one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `eix` tool (from `app-portage/eix`):

```
eix --in-overlay OVERLAY_NAME
```

From `man eix`:

> --in-overlay overlay
>                Only match packages with at least one version in an overlay matching overlay.
>
> --only-in-overlay overlay
>                 Only match packages which have only versions in an overlay matching overlay.

If you're not familiar with `eix`: before use you must must build packages database using `eix-update`. You may need to use `eix-layman add` first.

Also check out `man eix` for more examples.

Comment: thanx, but i need see list of all packages.

Comment: It gives you list of packages: http://paste.org/57858

Comment: If you want only names you can use `--only-names` switch...

Comment: eix --in-overlay robbat2 - No matches found - http://goo.gl/RXbmC

Comment: Real name for this overlay (defined in `/var/lib/layman/robbat2/profiles/repo_name`) is `overlay-dev/robbat2`, so you should use `eix --in-overlay overlay-dev/robbat2`